# How to call _IntfCopy procedure using Delphi's inline assembler

Tags: delphi

`procedure _IntfCopy` is defined in `System.pas`:

```
procedure _IntfCopy(var Dest: IInterface; const Source: IInterface);
```

Just wondering if it is possible to call `_IntfCopy` procedure using Delphi inline assembler:

```
procedure Test;
asm
  ...
  call _IntfCopy;
end;
```

That always resulted to `E2003 Undeclared identifier: '_IntfCopy'` during compiling.

A simple coding:

```
var a, b: IInterface;
begin
  a := b;
end;
```

produce in Delphi assembler:

```
mov eax,$0042481c
mov edx,[$00424820]
call @IntfCopy
```

But I couldn't find a way to write inline Delphi assembler to do IInterface reference via assignment operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic incantation is:

```
call System.@IntfCopy
```